# Why they have to be on the same line: (c = getchar()) != EOF)

Tags: c

I don't understand.
I try to write a program to eliminate white spaces:

```
int c;
c = getchar();
while (c!= EOF) {

    //do things
}
```

The above code causes a lot of the first input characters to output to screen,
yet

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

solved the problem.
Why?
How do I debug to understand this better?

Comment: `c = getchar();` <-- Look at the position of this line. Is it in the while loop getting executed ?

Comment: It also eliminates code and behavior duplication that way. Situations like that are when you'll find things that look like `while ((x = func()) != value)`. It looks cleaner, and it's less difficult to comprehend as a result IMHO. Unless you prefer `for (c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar())` or `for(;;){c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break; ...}`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
> ```
>
> solved the problem

- Because your are calling `getchar()` on each iteration, and in the first code you wasn't.

Try this

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void removeSpaces()
{
    do {
        chr = getchar();
    } while ((chr != EOF) && (isspace(chr) != 0));
}
```

then just call `removeSpaces()` whenever you want to remove spaces.

Comment: I mistrust `do … while` loops, especially in the hands of the inexperienced.  Here, it is OK because there's nothing after the `chr = getchar();` operation except the test, but there's a tendency for people to add code after the `getchar()` without testing the value for EOF until the end of the loop, which often leads to unhappiness.